# Question about graduate textbook and class.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, soft-question, education

I am a senior in mathematics, and I have had Advanced Cal I, but currently go to a no name school (there were only three people in the class). I have also taken Advanced Cal II as an independent study. We used Fitzpatrick's Advanced Calculus. I was able to get through Chapter 13 (I have also had an Introductory Topology class). I did fairly well in the classes. Furthermore, I have been accepted to a decent graduate program which uses Rudin's Real & Complex Analysis (as most do) for the Graduate Analysis I and II classes. I understand that it may be difficult to give feed back, but my professor said that it is a big jump from Fitzpatrick to Papa Rudin, but he said it has been a while since he looked at Rudin. My question is is it a bad idea to jump from Fitzpatrick to Papa Rudin, and if so any advice or recommendations?

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what school will you be going to. I ask because I want to look at their courses. Sometimes schools want you to take their adv Calc which is senior first year grad since the qualifier could be based on it. With that being said, this school may use Rudin's R and C for a more elevated analysis which the qualifier isn't based on.

Comment: I actually looked in detail, because I did not think of that. It seems like the qualifier is based on their undergraduate advanced Calculus sequence. That being said I think that would mean that I would take the undergraduate versions with baby Rudin. Is it commmon for the qualifiers to be based on the undergraduate analysis courses? Thanks so much.

Comment: It isn't usually called an undergraduate but a senior level first year graduate course. It is common for this to occur and students to take the course even if they have had an equivalent course else where since this will be taught in mind of what the grad students need to know to do well on the qualifier. Additionally, you will be able to get prepared to take big Rudin as well if you so please once you finish the year long analysis course for the quals.

Answer (score 0):

I actually like Fitzgerald, but I think it's a pretty big jump from Fitzgerald to Real and Complex. If you can, I'd read the first 8 chapters of PMA Rudin (so called baby Rudin), and supplement that with Calculus on Manifolds for multivariable stuff. If you don't have time though, the first 8 chapters of baby Rudin I would say are definitely required to really tackle graduate real analysis.